# xcode error Lexical or Preprocessor issue

Tags: xcode, smtp

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](http://techgeekanirudh.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/stmp-client-server-in-xcode.html) and am encountering this error. If somebody could help me it would be much, much appreciated.

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

That header is probably not in your project navigator in xcode, You need to find the file in finder and drag it into xcode and place it in your project navigator

Comment: It is in the project navigator.

Comment: Is it red in the project navigator?

Answer (score 0):

A few options I can suggest:

- Add the framework part of the path `#import <SMTPSend/NSData+Base64Additions>` (also if this is a framework, you should probably use these enclosures: `<.../file.h>` instead of quotes)
- Add the frameworks path to your build settings ( Framework Search Paths )
- Make sure the framework is in the `Link Binary With Libraries` section
- Remove the framework reference from the project organizer pane (cmd+1), then drag it back in (refreshes the path for the file)
- Clean/Clean Build Folder/Rebuild

Hope one of those helps!